# What c# libraries can I use to create .bundle (zipped) files for use in iPhone SDK

Tags: c#, iphone, zip, archive

I've just created a "bundle creator" app and I'd like to be able to produce a zipped .bundle file rather than have to copy the whole bundle folder.

ICSharpCode.SharpZLib Zip library to scuessfully create a archive file however the iPhone doesnt appear to uncompress it.

Answer (score 0):

[ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) on Google Code might help you. Here is [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/wiki/PageName).

Comment: Thanks bu tIm trying to create the zip using c# not objective-c

Comment: Since the iPhone doesn't support C#, I wasn't sure why you added that tag and thought it was a typo. Apologies.

Comment: Unfortunately so! Im writing a bundle admin tool for all the windows users then a techy will compile it with the app (or thats they way my client hopes it will work!!!!)

Answer (score 0):

[SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) works well.

Edit: OK, so it didn't work for you I see in your edit ... but it's worked well for me in other cases (by which I mean non-iPhone).

Comment: Which arhive algorithm did you use?

Comment: I used the default with a compression level of 9